# How to change Azure local deploy directory?

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

I would like to know how to change default Azure SDK local deploy directory?

Default Azure SDK local deploy directory is **C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\dftmp***, but I would like to change it. I have already google it, but with no success.

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the environment variable _CSRUN_STATE_DIRECTORY to location where the output of the build would be deployed. See [here](http://blogs.citytechinc.com/pmcloughlin/?p=229)

**Update**: Since the link is broken. To set environment variable

Right clicking Computer, selecting Properties, Advanced System Settings, and Environment variables and setting the _CSRUN_STATE_DIRECTORY environment variable. After rebooting you will not encounter the issue…

Comment: This link is (probably) similar to the broken link: [Windows Azure - Resolving 'The Path is too long after being fully qualified Error Message'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/01/14/windows-azure-path-too-long.aspx).