# Package name path - The path is too long after being fully qualified

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, iis, package

While trying to run code locally for testing, I get a path too long server error. I don't have much control over the actual files, particularly because we're dealing with external packages, but it has to be the temp file location causing the issue, the only path in the error that breaks is the one here:

```
file:///C:/Users/AndrewXXXXXXX/AppData/Local/dftmp/Resources/f18770c5-ec0e-43b9-a034-5fdfb17ca0ea/temp/temp/RoleTemp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/15dc497d/324adb56/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Data/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Data.DLL
```

That's 300 characters, much of it taken up by the stupidly long package name, which repeats twice. The actual file in the project bin has a length of 164 characters, so that isn't the issue. Is there anything I can do to move this temp folder? I changed my system's `%temp%` to `D:\Temp\` hoping it was using that, but no luck.

Comment: I think moving it is going to be your best bet.

Comment: @Rickjames but how?

Comment: I had this error, I closed all running VS IDE sessions and Compute Emulators.  Then restarted VS and project ran fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im guessing by the folder structure, your working with azure? You should be able to change the path to the temporary folder by setting the _CSRUN_STATE_DIRECTORY to a shorter path. Have a look at the following.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jnak/2010/01/14/windows-azure-resolving-the-path-is-too-long-after-being-fully-qualified-error-message/
or here [How to change Azure local deploy directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369114/how-to-change-azure-local-deploy-directory)

Comment: No such environment variable exists in my system settings.

Comment: how bout creating that variable then?